# keyboard still working after calling free_irq(1, NULL);

Tags: kernel-modules, c, interrupt

I'm developing a kernel module which free the IRQ number 1 in order to disable the keyboard in Intel architectures. according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_%28PC_architecture%29) the IRQ 1 is used for keyboard. but after building and inserting the module, the keyboard still working.

is it an IRQ number issue or freeing IRQ is not enough to disable keyboard interrupts

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
static int __init mymodule_init(void) {
      /* IRQ1 is the IRQ of the keyboard controlled under intel architecuter */
 free_irq(1, NULL);

        return 0;
}
static void __exit mymodule_exit(void) {
        return;
}
module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Is your ketboard connected to the intel 8042 or to USB?  IRQ1 is for the 8042 only (legacy keyboard).

Comment: i think it's the intel 8042 keyboard, I'm working with my laptop keyboard

Comment: do `watch cat /proc/interrupts`  and see if the number changes when you tap keys or hold shift etc... that works here.